# Rails axlsx-rails: ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

I'm having problems generating an excel report using the axlsx-rails gem since I'm getting `Completed 406 Not Acceptable ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat` all the time.

I have a form in the index view with two buttons, one of them submits a search requestshowing the search result as a html table and the other one should allow the user to generate an excel report with the result of the search.

I'm using `rails 5.1.6`:

```
gem 'rubyzip', '>= 1.2.1'
gem 'axlsx', git: 'https://github.com/randym/axlsx.git', ref: 'c8ac844'
gem 'axlsx_rails'
```

In the controller:

`orders_controller.rb`

```
def index
  orders = request.query_string.present? ? Order.search(params, 
  current_user) : Order.pendientes

 if params[:button] == 'report'
   @orders = orders
   respond_to do |format| 
     format.xlsx
     response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; 
     filename="Informe_Pedidos.xlsx"'
   end
 else
  @orders = orders.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}").page(params[:page]).per(params[:paginas])
 end
end
```

I have also added this to the mime_types initializer:

`Mime::Type.register "application/xlsx", :xlsx`

And I finally have this template:
`orders/views/index.xlsx.axlsx`

EDIT:

The submit buttoin logic in the view:

```
<%=button_tag type: 'submit', value: 'report', class: 'btn btn-outline-  danger' do %>
  <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<%end%>
```

This is the full request and error message:

```
Started GET "/orders?utf8=%E2%9C%93&f_fin=2018-04-19&f_inicio=&      pendientes=true&favoritos=true&planta=&paginas=&bu                    tton=report&pedido=&sap_cod=&descripcion=&ref=&ot=&desc_ot=&ubicacion=" for  10.0.2.2 at 2018-04-19 17:37:04 +0000
Processing by OrdersController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "f_fin"=>"2018-04-19", "f_inicio"=>"",  "pendientes"=>"true", "favoritos"=>"true", "pl                   anta"=>"",    "paginas"=>"", "button"=>"report", "pedido"=>"", "sap_cod"=>"",   "descripcion"=>"", "ref"=>"", "ot"=>""                   , "desc_ot"=>"",   "ubicacion"=>""}
 User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" =  $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [                   ["id", 1],    ["LIMIT", 1]]
 Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you already solved this issue. But if not, try to add "Format: xlsx" to your form.

For example:

```
<%= form_for User.new, index_path(format: :xlsx) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try next solution:

```
...
format.xlsx do
  render xlsx: "index", filename="Informe_Pedidos"
end
...
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but it gives another different error related with pagination. Looks like it tries to render HTML instead of XLSX.

Comment: @ErnestoG Which url you use when making request? It should be something like `http://yourhost/orders.xlsx?param1=foo&param2=bar` etc.

Comment: It was finally a matter of getting rid of the "format" block. Since I was processing the request through a submit button It was always trying to process thriugh HTML and never hitting the block. Just calling `render xlsx: "index", filename="Informe_Pedidos` right after the if statement where I check if the request comes from one or another button is enough

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've got in a production application right now. I may have written it, but it was awhile ago, so I can't say much about it other than 'it works'. I believe the `type` param is picking up the mime type from the initializer, which is the same as you have. Hope it helps!

```
def show
  generated_report = GeneratedReport.find(params[:id])
  send_data(
    generated_report.file_data,
    filename: generated_report.filename,
    type: :xlsx
  )
end
```